# Erro de conexão ao usar Logs do Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Estou tentando ver os sqls gerados pelo Hibernate  em minha aplicação JAVA
mas estou tendo problemas pois ao adicionar  os dois comandos abaixo são lançadas algumas exceções.

Comandos que estou inserindo no persistence.xml:

```
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property> <!-- Show SQL in console -->
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property> <!-- Show SQL formatted -->
```

Meu persistence.xml completo está assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="XXXXXX" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/xxxx_new"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="&lt;property name=&quot;hibernate.show_sql&quot;&gt;true&lt;/property&gt;"/>                         
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property> <!-- sem essas duas linhs funciona -->
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property> <!-- sem essas duas linhs funciona -->
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Quando adiciono as 2 linhas para ver o log tenho a seguinte Exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
Error parsing XML [line : -1, column : -1] : cvc-complex-type.4: O atributo 'value' deve aparecer no elemento 'property'.
Error parsing XML [line : -1, column : -1] : cvc-complex-type.2.1: O elemento 'property' não deve ter um caractere ou um item com informações do elemento [children] porque o tipo de conteúdo do tipo é vazio.
Error parsing XML [line : -1, column : -1] : cvc-complex-type.4: O atributo 'value' deve aparecer no elemento 'property'.
Error parsing XML [line : -1, column : -1] : cvc-complex-type.2.1: O elemento 'property' não deve ter um caractere ou um item com informações do elemento [children] porque o tipo de conteúdo do tipo é vazio.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere os comandos para estes:

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
```

Utilizando a propriedade `value` para setar valor.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente obrigado.